# Alignment Issue - Nested Divs - Images

Tags: html, css

I want to have a background div with a green color. The photo should be in the top left corner and text should wrap around it (not over it). A different div should be displayed at the end in the lower right corner. Currently I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
           .UseA
           {
             display:block;
             text-indent:70px;
             border-radius: 10px;
             background: url('paper.gif') left top no-repeat #BADA55;
             /*background: url('paper.gif') left top no-repeat #BADA55;*/
             /*background: #BADA55;*/
             min-height:50px;
             width:300px;        
           }

           .UseA .dta
           {
             display:block;
             text-indent:15px;
             border-radius: 10px;
             width:130px;
             background-color:grey;
             color:white;
             position:relative; /*Relative to normal position*/
             left:150px; /*Move away from left*/
             top:3px;
           }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>    




        <div class="UseA">
                Hello , My name is Jim ..
                         <div class="dta">something here</div>
        </div>

  </body>
 </html>
```

This code does not support long texts. If the text is long (observe picB), it writes on the image, not around it,and pushes the grey div down. I want to have the grey div always inside the main green div on it lower right corner. These are the screen shots

[image]

Image A is the desired image, but long text runs over the image and not around it along with the grey box sliding down.

Any suggestions on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use padding. Not text-indent

http://jsfiddle.net/AWXEx/

```
.UseA
       {
         display:block;
         padding-left:70px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         background: url('paper.gif') left top no-repeat #BADA55;
         /*background: url('paper.gif') left top no-repeat #BADA55;*/
         /*background: #BADA55;*/
         min-height:50px;
         width:230px;        
       }

       .UseA .dta
       {
         display:block;
        text-align: center;
         padding:1px 15px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         width:130px;
         background-color:grey;
         color:white;
         position:relative; /*Relative to normal position*/
         left:50px; /*Move away from left*/
         top:3px;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `position: relative`. In your case, you can use `margin` and `padding` to adjust the elements accordingly. When you wrap the upper text in an extra `div`, you have more freedom in adjusting the lower text with `margin` only

HTML

```
<div class="UseA">
    <div class="msg">Hello , My name is Jim. What is yours?
        What if this is a long text? And what if it gets even longer?</div>
    <div class="dta">something here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.UseA {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.UseA .msg {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.UseA .dta {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnuAP/)

Answer (score 0):

This css properties make the magic

**- white-space: nowrap;

 - overflow: hidden; 

 - text-overflow: ellipsis;**

add it to the **.UseA** class